# jQuery find and replace ignoring tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

I've built a little find and replace function with jQuery. ([See functional example here](https://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/u6fef1eg/3/)) It works well until you consider formatting tags.

Assuming the following html:

```
Here <i>is</i> my <b>sample</b> text
```

If you search for `sample text`, the search fails due to the bold tags.

The acceptable result would be removing `<b>sample</b> text`, replacing it with whatever you have entered for the replacement. It should leave the italic tag alone. How could this be accomplished?

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
function findandreplace() {
  var text = $('.editor').html(),
      find = $('#find').val(),
      replace = $('#replace').val(),
      newText = text.replace(new RegExp(find, "g"), replace)
  $('.editor').html(newText);
}
```

Comment: check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/u6fef1eg/5/ you can replace the word in italic or bolded

Comment: @MoolsBytheway, doesn't seem to work for me? Just to be clear, I need to replace `<b>sample</b> text` when searching for `sample text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text()` to ignore the tags and replace the text, but cannot retain the tags. Is this you want?

```
function findandreplace() {
  var text = $('.editor').text(),
      find = $('#find').val(),
      replace = $('#replace').val(),
      newText = text.replace(new RegExp(find, "g"), replace)
  $('.editor').html(newText);
}
```

**Edit:** This one satisfies the requirement, however we can generalize/optimize it further for required tags.

```
function findandreplace() {
     var find = $('#find').val(),
         replace = $('#replace').val()

     $('.editor').find('b').contents().unwrap();
     var text = $('.editor').html();
     var newText = text.replace(new RegExp(find, "g"), replace)
     $('.editor').html(newText);
}
```

Comment: The tags in the searched phrase can be removed, but other tags must remain.

Comment: I appreciate it, but this method has problems. For example, if you had code of `here <b>is</b> my <b>test</b>` and you searched for "test", it would also strip the bold tag from the word "is".